# Using Pytorch how to define a tensor with indices and corresponding values

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, sparse-matrix

### Problem

I have a list of indices and a list of values like so:

```py
i = torch.tensor([[2, 2, 1], [2, 0, 2]])
v = torch.tensor([1, 2, 3])
```

I want to define a (`3x3` for the example) matrix which contains the values `v` at the indices `i` (`1` at position `(2,2)`, `2` at position `(2, 0)` and `3` at position `(1,2)`):

```py
tensor([[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 3],
        [2, 0, 1]])
```

### What I have tried

I can do it using a trick, with `torch.sparse` and `.to_dense()` but I feel that it's not the "pytorchic" way to do that nor the most efficient:

```py
f = torch.sparse.FloatTensor(indices, values, torch.Size([3, 3]))
print(f.to_dense())
```

Any idea for a better solution ?
Ideally I would appreciate a solution at least as fast than the one provided above.
Of course this was just an example, no particular structure in tensors `i` and `v` are assumed (neither for the dimension).

Comment: If you ask me, it is "PyTorch"-ic enough !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an alternative, as below:

```py
import torch

i = torch.tensor([[2, 2, 1], [2, 0, 2]])
v = torch.tensor([1, 2, 3], dtype=torch.float)   # enforcing same data-type

target = torch.zeros([3,3], dtype=torch.float)   # enforcing same data-type
target.index_put_(tuple([k for k in i]), v)

print(target)
```

The `target` tensor will be as follows:

```bash
tensor([[0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 3.],
        [2., 0., 1.]])
```

[This medium.com blog article](https://medium.com/emulation-nerd/every-index-based-operation-youll-ever-need-in-pytorch-a7cef65ea94c) provides a comprehensive list of all **index** functions for PyTorch Tensors.

Comment: As to which is **more** PyTorch-ic, I am not sure. One thing is for sure, if you are working with sparse tensors, you will save lot of memory (_unless you have to frequently convert them to dense tensors_)

Comment: Nice, quicker than my solution with `sparse` !

Comment: On-liner: `torch.zeros([3,3]).index_put_(tuple(k for k in i), v)`. I don't believe you need to cast the tensor as it's already `dtype=float`.